# unable to start the oracle TNSListener service(Oracle19c) - "OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListenerGLDB"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, listener, oracle19c, ora-12154

1. Initially Oracle 19c(Database and Client64) was installed and TNS Listener was configured under "Net Configuration Assistant" from the following path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Oracle - OraDB19Home1\Configuration and Migration Tools". It was running fine for more than 6 months.
2. 2 days before we got TNSListner error and unable to connect to the database. We are able to re-start all the Oracle services except TNSLISTENER service. While restarting the service getting following error "The oracleoradb19home1tnllistenerGLDB service on local computer started and stopped. some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."
3. When we tried to check the Listener configuration, unable to invoke the "Net Configuration Assistant" application from the following path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Oracle - OraDB19Home1\Configuration and Migration Tools".
4. In Net Manager window also, we could not see the Listener.
5. After restarting the system also , unable to restart the Listener service.
   Note: Oracle server is under domain user.

Getting "ORA-12154 TNS could not resolve the correct identifier specified" error while loading data into Oracle Database.

Comment: What changed on that system?

Comment: ORA-12154 has nothing to do with the listener.  It is purely, 100% a client-side problem.  Either the net service name the client specified cannot be found in tnsnames.ora, or the tnsnames.ora file itself could not be found.  As a result, the request was never sent to the listener. So if you get that AND you can't start the listener, you either have mutliple problems, or you have a fundamental config problem.  If it was working before, what changed?